# Eclipse / Packages in "Project Explorer" display is dropping leading components

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently updated my Eclipse to 2021-06 and have a sudden change in appearance for the packages when using "Project Explorer" - the packages still display correctly when using "Package Explorer".

What setting changed during the update that I can change to get back the classical display as used in "Package Explorer"?

Correct "Package Explorer" display using package display "flat":

[image: Desired Packages Display]

Very Confusing and Unwanted "Project Explorer" display using package display "flat":

[image: Very Confusing and Unwanted Display]

Java package folders:

```
tree .
.
└── com
    └── newsrx
        └── jam
            ├── api
            │   └── GreetingController.java
            ├── Application.java
            ├── config
            │   └── SecurityConfiguration.java
            ├── NpmPackages.java
            ├── user
            │   ├── ep
            │   │   └── UserInfoEndpoint.java
            │   ├── UserInfo.java
            │   ├── User.java
            │   └── UserSession.java
            └── views
                ├── dashboard
                │   ├── ChartSeries.java
                │   ├── DashboardEndpoint.java
                │   └── HealthGridItem.java
                └── LoginScreen.java
```

Misc Info:

```
Eclipse.org Eclipse Java Development Tools  3.18.800.v20210611-1600 org.eclipse.jdt

Eclipse.org Eclipse Platform    4.20.0.v20210611-1600   org.eclipse.platform
```

```sh
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute

java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

Java→Appearance

[image: Java→Appearance]

Comment: What do you have in the preferences in _Java > Appearance_?

Comment: Post edited to add screenshot of Java→Appearance

Comment: _Java > Appearance_ looks good. It might be an additional plugin that you have installed. What do you have in the _Projects Explorer_ in the _Filters and Customization_ dialog (hit the filter icon to get the dialog) in the tabs _Content_ and _Pre-set filters_?

Comment: Active Filters:

[x] .JETEmitters

[x] Empty library containers

[x] Empty parent packages

[x] Gradle *

[x] Import declarations

[x] Inner class files

[x] Java output folders

[x] Package declarations

Comment: User filters: empty

Comment: Content: All except Nested Projects checked.